# Let a,b,c be distinct non-negative numbers. If the vectors ai+aj+ck,i+k and ci+cj+bk lie in a plane, then relation between a, b and c

Tags: vectors, 3d

My Question is How to proceed with the question. I mean there are two ways:-
Either one could apply the scalar triple product and solve the determinant equated to 0 which has provided me with the relation of a Geometric Progression.
Or We Can Multiply 2 of the vectors by some variables and add them to form the third vector and solve accordingly but consider multiplying the first and the third vector given and no solution can be obtained.
Can Someone Explain to me the error in my work in an elementary fashion? I'd be really grateful

(Please excuse me for being unable to attach a pic for further explanation as I am new on the site and not familiar with the homework rules)

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What did you do that's a mistake?

Comment: If you multiply the first and the third vector with variables each, add them to form the middle vector i+k, there is no solution.

Comment: Thanks for replying!

Comment: Oh also, you don't mean they lie in a plane. You mean they lie in a two-dimensional subspace. Any three points lie in a plane.

Comment: There Are 3 vectors, I used  two of them to form up a variable vector in which when right values are plugged in lead to the remaining vector. And I am unable to find a solution this way

Comment: I understand. Writing the answer now.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Please edit your post and clean it up. At the moment, it seems incoherent.

Comment: I have got an answer @The Pointer and I am happy with the way this question is, If you want to have it deleted/edited or something, go on

Comment: @ModestPelican Yes, but we want well-constructed questions for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: @ThePointer That's like your opinion, man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What Went Wrong**

Okay, the problem is that in fact the vectors $(a,a,c)$ and $(c,c,b)$ are in the same one-dimensional subspace (that is, they are scalar multiples of each other).

Your correct solution tells us that the numbers are in geometric progression, and in particular we have $c = \lambda a$, $b = \lambda c$ for some scalar $\lambda$. Therefore, we have
$$
(a,a,c) = (a,a,\lambda a) = a(1,1,\lambda),
$$
and
$$
(c,c,b) = (c,c,\lambda c) = c(1,1,\lambda).
$$
It follows that any linear combination of $(a,a,c)$ and $(c,c,b)$ will lie in the one-dimensional subspace $\langle (1,1,\lambda)\rangle$, which clearly doesn't contain $(1,0,1)$.

**How to Fix It**

You can salvage your second approach by using a different pair of vectors. In my opinion, this is much more elegant than using matrix determinants, which are unnecessarily complicated. Since the vectors are coplanar, there exist scalars $\lambda, \mu$ such that
$$
\lambda(a,a,c) + \mu(1,0,1) =(\lambda a + \mu, \lambda a, \lambda c + \mu) = (c,c,b).
$$
Since the first two entries of the middle vector are equal, we have $\mu = 0$, so
$$
(\lambda a, \lambda a, \lambda c) = (c,c,b).
$$
It follows immediately that $c = \lambda a$ and $b = \lambda c$.

Comment: I Get It Now! Thank You so much

Comment: You're welcome! By the way, despite what I said about elegance, there's nothing wrong with thinking in terms of matrix determinants. That was how I first did it too, and it's great that you're comfortable with the matrix theory